# Is it ok that send 404 status for searchs that don't have any results?

Tags: search, search-engine

I wanna write a search plugin for a CMS. my search url is something like this: **domain.com/serach.php?q=blah**. now I wanna send **404 status** on search queries that don't have any results. is it ok for search engines? I don't want that search engines send users too my search script that don't have any results. for example if "**something**" search query don't have any results in my website, search engines get that and don't show **domain.com/search.php?q=something** in its result. how can I do that?

Comment: Why would a search engine index random searches that don't find anything? What pages would have links to them?

Comment: Sometimes the google bot modifies query strings randomly, I know that because once I launched a site and we would get an email for every error ont he site including 404s, we got mailbombed as result of the google bot testing random querys strings.

Comment: So you want to detect a search engine bot request somehow (user-agent?) and return a 404? I don't think that's the behavior GoogleBot is expecting. It's probably looking for a string on the results page indicating no results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Juhana, how would robots land on a page that shows no result in the first place?

Besides, be aware that all query parameters are not always taken into account or considered leading to different pages = they might be considered as the same canonical page.
For example, especially if you have more than one ("`q`") parameter(s) in reality, the fact that you reply with 404 for a given query might lead to other queries on your script `search.php` be considered as 404.

Thus i would not recommend what you're suggesting. Use maybe the `<meta name="robots" content="noindex">` tag instead.

Comment: sometimes in google results I redirect to search pages that don't have any results. and I don't want this for my website

Comment: use of meta tag is ok for whole search script, but how can I define my search page to search engines? that they show my search pages that have results in its results?

Comment: here in the google documentation it says the tag is considered on a "page-by-page basis" : http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=93710 meaning you can dynamically add the tag thanks to your server-side scripting language (let's say it's PHP for instance) the same way you generate your search results : 0 result found => add the tag, not too hard :)